# Why are closed manifolds defined as they are?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

The standard definition of a closed manifold is the following:

> A closed manifold is a manifold without boundary that is compact.

I am wondering, why we request that the manifold is compact. As I understand, we try to generalise the idea of *closed curves*, such as circle, and *closed surfaces*, such as torus. (In this context, I think of closed (for curves) as if we are at one point on a curve and move in either direction for long enough, we will once come back to this same point). Now, it's obvious to request that the manifold has no boundary. This is also clearly not enough, as we have simple objects, such as open unit balls, which have no boundaries, yet they are not "closed", as we intuitively imagine.

So I guess because of this we require that the manifold is compact. But why *compact*? Why not closed? Or some other condition. What makes compact the right choice? I would appreciate if someone can motivate this definition and (at least intuitively) explain why compact property gives us exactly what we wish.

Comment: Closed surfaces may or may not have closed only geodesics. The torus does not.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio For torus, I still intuitively consider it "closed", as it has no border, and just naturally seems closed; just as circle for example.  I have some problems with defining this "closed" for surfaces (for curves, I think my definition is fine). I believe that this definition of closed manifolds is exactly generalisation/formalisation of my definition for closed curves, but I don't intuitively understand why.

Comment: "Why not closed?" In what sense closed? Topologically? Every manifold is closed in itself. Being closed requires a space and a super space. Compactness does not.

Comment: Compact manifolds are closed whenever they are submanifolds of some other manifold.

Comment: A 'closed manifold" is just a terminology. Are you asking about historic origin of this terminology? (From what I understand, it goes back to the 19th century.) Are you asking why are they interesting? There are many interesting questions about manifolds which are non-compact or/and have nonempty boundary.

Comment: Closed manifolds satisfy Poincare duality (with appropriate orientability/connectedness/coefficient choices).